# Is The Mistcaller placing a buffed state that triggers when ever I draw a card, rather than buffing cards of my deck in place?

Tags: hearthstone

I played a match a while ago and in that match I played a Golden Monkey after previously having played a Mistcaller. My hand got replaced, and as expected, those cards all lost the Mistcaller buff.

But, to my surprise, the legendaries I drew from my deck retained the Mistcaller +1/+1 buff.

**Is Mist Caller placing a buffed state that triggers when ever I draw a card, rather than buffing cards of my deck in place?**

Comment: That's a good question. In my opinion, he buffs the cards just before you draw them

Comment: That is a really good find, post it on the official forums too.

Comment: @Shaeldon: I don't like to post there. IO ahve psoted there 3 times so far. 1 time reporting a bug, 1 time reporting a bug that made me loose cards(!!!!) and one time asking for clarification about some behaving. None of the 3 posts has even a single answer after more than a year is past now.

Answer (score 6):

Mist caller creates an On-draw trigger to apply the +1/+1 buff to any minion cards drawn from the deck to your hand.  Cards pulled from the deck via other means (for example, by Deathlord) bypass this trigger and thus do not get the buff.  In addition, cards added to your deck **after** playing mistcaller (for example, via Entomb) *will* get the buff.

You can look at the [Advanded Rule Book](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Advanced_rulebook), specifically the [Drawing a card](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Advanced_rulebook#Drawing_a_Card) section for a lot of details about how card draws and effects tied to it work.

For now, the way this works [is not considered a bug](https://twitter.com/CM_Whirthun/status/636203158457290753).  [Ben Brode tweeted at one point](https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/665219870485667840) it is was implemented this way do to server performance concerns

> @Freakythomsn no - we had to do that last second to keep the servers performant - we are working on a better way.

Answer (score 3):

The mist caller adds +1/+1 to all cards on your hand and all cards you draw after you played him.

If you would play a "Varian Wryn" for example the minions you play are not "drawn" and don´t get the buff.

I know that i saw that in a video once but i can´t find it right now.

Comment: Although the card text of Varian Wryn says you "draw" cards... Then, I think there is a bug either in the implementation of Varian Wryn or Mistcaller, if it is true what you are saying. But I am not sure about that... ;-)

Comment: Noticed this playing Tavern Brawl last night, technically the game mode is choosing 3 cards for you and letting you choose one, however, Mist Callers buff only affected what was in my hand at the time and the cards that I drew from either a "draw at the end of your turn" card or another forced draw method and not when I got cards in this way. Maybe that provides some insight?

Comment: @Atom: not at all, as Mistcaller states it gives +1/+1 to minions in your hand and deck. I would expect 1. neither hand nor deck has buff anymore. if deck remained I had expacted hand remained aswell. but in enither case I would have expected what you mentioned.

Comment: Varian draws and plays the cards at the same time. The buff is applied after the game added the drawn card to your hand. another example for that weird behavior is Varian after you have Chromagus on the field.